# Change Class If Another Class Exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Slidebars (http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/) to generate push menus for my website. When off-canvas menu is open, it adds class called 'sb-active-left'.

I want it to change menu icon depending on if menu is opened or closed.

HTML

```
<div class="fixed sb-slide">
    <a class="sb-toggle-left"><i class="icon"></i></a>
</div>
```

JS

```
if ($(".sb-active-left")[0]){
    $('.sb-toggle-left .icon').addClass('icon-remove');
}

else {
    $('.sb-toggle-left .icon').addClass('icon-menu');
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are binding this event?  When does your javascript run?

Answer (score 1):

use the hasClass() method of jQuery....

```
if ( $elem.hasClass('sb-active-left') ) {
     do something
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: This is a nice answer he could just have added `$('.sb-active-left')[0].lenght`?? would that work?

Comment: @Sebastien, do you mean $('sb-active-left').length? That method requires querying the entire DOM for a class (which could potentially be anywhere in the doc). The answer above is cleaner and probably more efficient.

Comment: Hey! @Jason  if ($('html').hasClass('sb-active-left') ) {
   $('.sb-toggle-left i').removeClass("icon-menu").addClass("icon-remove"); 
 } is this right?

Comment: You don't need this javascript at all.  His example is based on $elem being the element that has .sb-slidebar .sb-left and .sb-active.  You can do this purely with CSS because the helper class sb-active, and sb-active-left are placed on the html element.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with CSS. But the OP was already using jQuery, which I assumed was what he wanted to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Slidebars gives you this ability just using css styling look at the helper classes of the Slidebars usage documentation: http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/usage.php

> html.sb-active is present when either Slidebar is open.
>
> html.sb-active-left is present when the left Slidebar is open.
>
> html.sb-active-right is present when the right Slidebar is open.

you could use a style like this to change the style when any sidebar is open

```
html.sb-active .navbar .sb-toggle-left
{
  background-image: url(../someimage.png);
}
```

or more specifically alter only the left icon, when only the left sidebar is open

```
html.sb-active-left .navbar .sb-toggle-left
{
  background-image: url(../someimage.png);
}
```

According to your javascript it seems like you can just change the selector on your class from:

```
.icon-remove
{
   // do icon-remove stuff
}

.icon-menu
{
   // do icon menu stuff
}
```

to

```
html.sb-active-left .navbar .sb-toggle-left
{
     // do icon-remove stuff
}

.navbar .sb-toggle-left
{
     // do icon-menu stuff
}
```

and you can remove the corresponding javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could do everything you want just from css....

```
.sb-toggle-left .icon {
  // default formatting, like icon-remove
}

.sb-toggle-left.sb-active-left .icon {
  // formatting for active menu item, like icon-menu
}
```

You'll want to look for a pure CSS solution here. The problem with the javascript is that you'll have to monitor for changes as the Slidebar library might add or remove classes based on certain events.  (if you did use JQuery, you're looking for the hasClass method)

Answer (score 0):

use the hasClass() function to check.

```
$(".action").click(
    function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("red")) {
             $(this).removeClass("red");
             $(this).addClass("yellow");
    } else {
             $(this).removeClass("yellow");
             $(this).addClass("red");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j6bNR/ here is a demo

Answer (score 0):

From your question I presume you are using FA or another icon set, and want to change the class, so a CSS solution wouldn't really help.

Unfortunately as Events aren't available with Slidebars yet, I would take control of the API, so you can execute extra code when you want.

First of all, you'll need to define your own instance of Slidebars when initiating the plugin.

```
var yourVariable = new $.slidebars()
```

You now dont have to use the standard control classes and can map the Slidebars controls to your own elements.

HTML

```
<div class="fixed sb-slide">
  <i id="menu-toggle" class="icon"></i>
</div>
```

JS

```
var yourVariable = new $.slidebars( {
    siteClose: false
});

// Cache toggle.
var toggle = $( '#menu-toggle' );

toggle.on( 'click', function( event ) {
    // Stop event propagation and behaviour.
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    // Toggle the left Slidebar
    yourVariable.slidebars.toggle( 'left' );

    // Change icon classes
    toggle.toggleClass( 'your-open-class your-close-class' );
} );

$( '#sb-site' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
    // Stop event propagation and behaviour.
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    // Make sure left Slidebar is open, close it and change icons.
    if ( yourVariable.slidebars.active('left') ) {
        yourVariable.slidebars.close();
        toggle.addClass( 'your-close-class' ).removeClass( 'your-open-class' );
    }
} );
```

I have also set this up in a fiddle, so you can see it working.

http://jsfiddle.net/2mX79/2/

I hope this helps.

Thanks, Adam